# How to compare value at specific position from DB to JSON variable in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In Database their is field as Diagnosis Reference and its value is like  "123456" 
In JSON value should display as :
Diagnosis Reference 1 : 1 ( Value at position 1)
Diagnosis Reference 2 : 2 ( Value at position 2)
Diagnosis Reference 3 : 3 ( Value at position 3)
Diagnosis Reference 4 : 4 ( Value at position 4)
Diagnosis Reference 5 : 5 ( Value at position 5)
Diagnosis Reference 6 : 6 ( Value at position 6)

How can I fetch value at each position from DB and compare it with JSON variables using JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value from the database into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler configured like:

[image]

then my assumption is that you need to execute some [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to get the JSON from some API endpoint.

At this stage you can add a [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) to [parse the JSON response](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) and compare it with the variable from the JDBC Request sampler

If your JSON response looks like:

```
[
  {
    "Diagnosis Reference 1": 1
  },
  {
    "Diagnosis Reference 2": 2
  },
  {
    "Diagnosis Reference 3": 3
  },
  {
    "Diagnosis Reference 4": 4
  },
  {
    "Diagnosis Reference 5": 5
  },
  {
    "Diagnosis Reference 6": 6
  }
]
```

you could use the code like:

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

vars.get('diagnosisReference_1').toCharArray().eachWithIndex { number, index ->
    if (response[index].get('Diagnosis Reference ' + number) != Character.getNumericValue(number)) {
        AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
        AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Numbers mismatch, expected: ' + number + ', got: ' + response[index].get('Diagnosis Reference ' + number))
    }
}
```